# How do you delete everything in a string that comes after a specific sequence of characters in Perl?

Tags: perl

In Perl, how can I delete everything in a string that comes right after a specific sequence of characters?

For example, if I had the string `TATPASSTERMABSD`, I want to only keep `TATPASS` because I want to delete everything that includes and comes right after `TERM`.

Comment: Right after, and including `TERM` if you want `TATPASS`

Answer (score 4):

What have you tried?

Is there some reason

```
    s/TERM.*//s
```

isn’t working for you?

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest this :

`my $var ='TATPASSTERMABSD';
$var =~s /(TATPASS).*/$1/s;`

so you'll keep TATPASS not depending to what comes after

Comment: Did you try out your code snippet? The result is `TATPASSTERM`, not `TATPASS`.

Comment: oh yeah sorry, i copied/pasted some wrong piece of code, you should have read /(TATPASS).*/$1/s of course. I change this right now.